# Convert Varchar date format from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyyMMdd in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2016, varchar

Hi I am trying to convert Varchar date format from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyyMMdd in SQL.I tried the below approaches but nothing is working.

```
Declare @doj VARCHAR(10)
Set @doj='2022-01-01'

Select convert (VARCHAR,@doj,112)
select format(@doj,'yyyyMMdd')
```

SQL engine is not converting to the required format.If I declared doj variable to date then it is working as expected.How to make it work if the doj is varchar?

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar` to store dates in the first place? As for why it isn't working, `CONVERT` with a style code is for converting to/from a `(n)(var)char` from/to *something else*, and `FORMAT` is for converting *to* a `(n)(var)char` from something else. Neither work when "converting" a `(n)(var)char` to a `(n)(var)char`, because there's nothing to convert; they are already both string based data types.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu, dates should be stored as date or datetime, but that said, if you want to keep the date as varchar you can simply use REPLACE or go the extra step to convert the field to date (CAST, CONVERT, or PARSE) and then use the FORMAT function.

Comment: Since you are starting with a string and not a date it appears all you need is `replace(@doj,'-','')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert to `datetime` and back again using [explicit `style` numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles):

```sql
Declare @doj VARCHAR(10) = '2022-01-01';
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @doj, 126), 112);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcadb7e74ff1f0de036edc1571494a4a)

Quite why you are storing dates in `varchar` in the first place is another question...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(date,'23/02/2023',105),112)
```

O/p :20230223

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(date,'23/02/2023',105),23)
```

O/P : 2023-02-23

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(date,'23-02-2023',105),23)
```

O/P : 2023-02-23

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).